# WinRT: Reading and deserializaing large amount of files takes too much time

Tags: json, optimization, io, windows-runtime

I have a Windows Store application which manages collection of objects and stores them in the application local folder. Those objects are serialized on the file system using JSON. As I need to be able to edit and persist those items individually I opted for individual files for each objects instead of one large file. Objects are stored following this pattern:

```
Local Folder
|
--- db
    |
    --- AB283376-7057-46B4-8B91-C32E663EC964
    |   |
    |   --- AB283376-7057-46B4-8B91-C32E663EC964.json
    |   --- AB283376-7057-46B4-8B91-C32E663EC964.jpg
    |
    --- B506EFC5-E853-45E6-BA32-64193BB49ACD
    |   |
    |   --- B506EFC5-E853-45E6-BA32-64193BB49ACD.json
    |   --- B506EFC5-E853-45E6-BA32-64193BB49ACD.jpg
    |
    ...
```

Each object has its folder node which will contains the JSON serialized object and other eventual resources.

Everything was fine when I made some writing, reading, deleting test. Where it got complicated is when I tried to load up large collections of object on application startup. I estimated that the largest amount of item one would store to 10000. So I wrote 10000 entries and then tried to load it... more than 3 minutes to the application to complete the operation, which of course is unacceptable.

So my questions are, What could be optimized in the code I made for reading and deserializing objects (code below)? Is there a way to implement a paging system so loading would be dynamic in my WinRT application? Is my storage method (pattern above) too heavy for in terms of IO/CPU? Am I missing something in WinRT?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Release>> GetReleases()
{
    List<Release> items = new List<Release>();

    var dbFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(dbName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    foreach (var releaseFolder in await dbFolder.GetFoldersAsync())
    {
        var releaseFile = await releaseFolder.GetFileAsync(releaseFolder.DisplayName + ".json");
        var stream = await releaseFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        using (var inStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Release));
            Release release = (Release)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
            items.Add(release);
        }

        stream.Dispose();
    }

    return items;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

NB: I already had a look as SQLite and I don't need such a sophisticated system.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly JSON.NET is better than the built in things. If you are not sending the data over the wire, then the quickest way is to do binary serialization rather than JSON or XML. Finally - think if you really need to load all the data when your application starts. Serialize your data as a list of binary records and create an index that will allow you to quickly jump to the range of records you actually need to use.

Comment: It seems that there is no binary serialization available out of the box in WinRT. I will try to find a library supporting that. I tested Json.Net and I noticed a 20% performance increase on loading so it is quite encouraging! I kind of like the atomicity of my objects because they can be written individually (like in a database). Serializing to a list would surely remove a bit of the file system IO overhead but won't be any faster on serialization.

Answer (score 1):

As Filip already mentioned, you probably don't need to load all data at startup. Even if you really want to show all the items in the first page (showing 10,000 items at once to a user doesn't sound like a good idea to me), you don't need to have all their properties available: usually only a couple of them are shown in the list, you need the rest of them when the user navigates to individual item details. You could have a separate "index" file containing only the data you need for the list. This does mean duplication, but it will help you with performance.

Although you've mentioned, you don't need SQLite as it is too sophisticated for your needs, you really should take a closer look at it. It is designed to efficiently handle structured data such as yours. I'm pretty sure if you switch to it, the performance will be much better and your code might end up even simpler in the end. Try it out.

Comment: Indeed, I don't need to load everything on startup, that is why I also suggested to have a kind of paging. I heard that WinRT provided virtualized list loaded thanks to the paging feature of certain web services, but since I am providing my own data source, I don't know how to implement it.
Concerning SQLite, my object model is quite simple and contains list referencing enumerations. The object model will get much more complicated if I use SQLite, something I don't even have to worry using serialization but I can't lie that having a queryiable data source would be nice so I'll have a try.